# care-o-bot bad stl files

Tags: ros, stl, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the care-o-bot stl files inside the cob_description package all start with the word 'solid'. The STL specification says that binary stl files *cannot* start with solid, this makes a lot of importers (like assimp) fail. We substituted all of them with 'xxxxx' and were able to convert the care-o-bot urdf to collada.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9844/care-o-bot-bad-stl-files/) by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 516 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest posting this to the care-o-bot users [mailing list](http://www.care-o-bot-research.org/contributing/mailing-lists) as I can't find a place to submit a ticket for them.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1